# Is there a way to plot a line that changes colour depending on Y-axis value? Like a gradient line using plt.plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, gradient

I have a large dataset with the temperature taken each day for several years. I want to plot the temperature on a graph. How can I have one continuous line that changes two colours depending on if the Y-value is above or below zero degrees?

This is the closest I've been able to get to the final look I want. However, it's a scatter plot and not a single line...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#'Date' is the combined datetime column, and 'T' is the temperature column
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['T'], c=df['T'] < 0, cmap='bwr', marker='.')

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')
plt.title('Temperature Over Time')

# Formatted x-axis labels to display only years
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())

plt.colorbar(label='Temperature (°C)')
plt.show()
```

[I am able to do it using the scatter function, but I want it to be a single continuous line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gqxA.png)

[Using a loop function just made it into loads of split lines which is not what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H2KD.png)

[Tried creating two lines but then you have these awkward jumps and lines are not connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K40Ky.png)

Tried doing an "if" "else" in the plt.plot but that didn't work either and when I delete the marker='.' my plt.plot just gets a value error
`raise ValueError(f"{v!r} is not a valid value for {k}")` saying that `Name: T, Length: 5848, dtype: bool is not a valid value for color`

Anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Have you checked masked arrays? [It should fit your needs.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/color_by_yvalue.html)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want it to be blue/red rather than a continuous gradient - see the data + results below.

Using `LineCollection` to plot a coloured *line*:
[image]

Simpler approach using `plt.scatter` which closely approximates a line:
[image]

The code shows two approaches: a more complex approach using `LineCollection` if you strictly need a line, and a much simpler approach using `plt.scatter` if you are okay with closely approximating a line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import pandas as pd

#
# Create some test data
#  A noisy periodic temperature profile over 2 years
#
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

days = pd.date_range(start='2022', end='2024', freq='D')

x = np.linspace(0, 2, num=len(days))
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x) * 10 + rng.normal(0, 5, size=len(x))

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': days, 'temperature': y})

#
# Smooth data into a line
#
window_size = 14
df['smoothed'] = df.temperature.rolling(window_size).mean()

#
# Make a Blue-Red colormap.
# And define a color norm that splits the data at temperature=0
#
blue_red_cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['tab:blue', 'tab:red'])
diverge_at_zero = mcolors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=0)

#
#Plot the original data
#
ax = plt.subplot()

p0 = ax.scatter(
    df.date, df.temperature, s=50, alpha=0.25,
    edgecolor='none', c=y,  cmap=blue_red_cmap, norm=diverge_at_zero,
    label='daily data'
)

#
#Graph the smoothed data
#
# Choose between a simple (plot_as_line=False) & more complex (plot_as_line=True)
# approach. The simpler approach yields a very close-looking approximation.

plot_as_line = True
# plot_as_line = False

if plot_as_line:
    #
    #Coloured smooth line using LineCollection
    #
    from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
    xy_points = np.column_stack([mdates.date2num(df.date), df.smoothed]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    line_segments = np.concatenate([xy_points[:-1], xy_points[1:]], axis=1)

    line_coll = LineCollection(line_segments, cmap=blue_red_cmap, norm=diverge_at_zero, lw=3)
    line_coll.set_array(df.smoothed) #set colours to temperature values

    p1 = ax.add_collection(line_coll)
    ax.figure.legend(handles=[p0, p1], labels=['data', f'{window_size}-day average'])
else:
    #
    # Simpler: using scatter plot to give the impression of a line
    #
    p1 = ax.scatter(
        df.date, df.smoothed,
        c=df.smoothed, cmap=blue_red_cmap, norm=diverge_at_zero,
        s=8, label=f'{window_size}-day average'
    )
    # ax.figure.legend()

#Additional plot formatting
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator=mdates.AutoDateLocator()))
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature ($^o$C)')
ax.figure.colorbar(mappable=p1, label='Temperature ($^o$C)')
ax.figure.set_size_inches(8.4, 2.5)
ax.set_title('Temperature over time')
```