# Gradient color on broken barh plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to reproduce this:
[image]

using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

colors = ["#CC5A43","#5375D4"]*3

data = {
    "year": [2004, 2022, 2004, 2022, 2004, 2022],
    "countries" : ["Sweden", "Sweden", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Norway", "Norway"],
    "sites": [13,15,4,10,5,8]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)

df['pct_change'] = df.groupby('countries', sort=True)['sites'].apply(
     lambda x: x.pct_change()).to_numpy()*-1
df['ctry_code'] = df.countries.astype(str).str[:2].astype(str).str.upper()
df = df.sort_values(['countries','year'], ascending=True ).reset_index(drop=True)
df['diff'] = df.groupby(['countries'])['sites'].diff()
df['diff'].fillna(df.sites, inplace=True)
countries = df.countries.unique()
code = df.ctry_code.unique()
pct_change = df.pct_change

x_coord = df.groupby('countries')['diff'].apply(lambda x: x.values) #convert the columns into numpy 2D array

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,5), facecolor = "#FFFFFF")
import matplotlib.cm
# use a colormap
cmap = plt.cm.RdBu

for i, (color, x_c, country) in enumerate(zip(colors,x_coord, countries)):
    ax.broken_barh([x_c], (i-0.2,0.4),facecolors=cmap(0.7),alpha= 0.2)

ax.scatter( df.sites, df.countries, marker="D", s=300, color = colors)

ax.set(xlim=[0, 16], ylim=[-1, 3])

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,20,5),labels = [0,5,10,15])
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="major",length=0,labelsize=14,colors= '#C8C9C9')

# Major ticks every 20, minor ticks every 5
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 16, 1)
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-', alpha=0.4, color = "#C8C9C9")
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.yticks([])
plt.box(False)

#add legend
labels = ['2004','2022']
colors = ["#5375D4","#CC5A43",]
lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color=c,  marker='D',linestyle='', markersize=12,) for c in colors]
leg = ax.get_legend()
plt.figlegend( lines,labels,
           labelcolor="#C8C9C9",
           bbox_to_anchor=(0.3, -0.1), loc="lower center",
            ncols = 2,frameon=False, fontsize= 12)
```

Which produces this:

[image]

My question is, how do i do the gradient on the broken_barh plots? I have tried to do a cmap on facecolors, but no luck.

I have also tried using ax.barh and ax.plot but still stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the answer of [How to fill matplotlib bars with a gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48814728/17457846)

I have made some changes of the function `gradientbars` in which I add some comments.

Also I have changed the size of the `scatter` plot for making it consistent with `broken_barh` and also for the `legend` which is disappeared.

Here are the full codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

def gradientbars(bars, ax):
    colors = [(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), ] # first color is red, last is blue
    cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
            "Custom", colors, N=256) # Conver to color map 
    mat = np.indices((10,10))[1] # define a matrix for imshow
    lim = ax.get_xlim()+ax.get_ylim()
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_zorder(1)
        bar.set_facecolor("none")
        
        # get the coordinates of the rectangle
        x_all = bar.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0]
        y_all = bar.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 1]
        
        # Get the first coordinate (lower left corner)
        x,y = x_all[0], y_all[0]
        # Get the height and width of the rectangle
        h, w = max(y_all) - min(y_all), max(x_all) - min(x_all)
        # Show the colormap 
        ax.imshow(mat, extent=[x,x+w,y,y+h], aspect="auto", zorder=0, cmap=cm, alpha=0.2)
    ax.axis(lim)

colors = ["#CC5A43","#5375D4"]*3

data = {
    "year": [2004, 2022, 2004, 2022, 2004, 2022],
    "countries" : ["Sweden", "Sweden", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Norway", "Norway"],
    "sites": [13,15,4,10,5,8]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)

df['pct_change'] = df.groupby('countries', sort=True)['sites'].apply(
     lambda x: x.pct_change()).to_numpy()*-1
df['ctry_code'] = df.countries.astype(str).str[:2].astype(str).str.upper()
df = df.sort_values(['countries','year'], ascending=True ).reset_index(drop=True)
df['diff'] = df.groupby(['countries'])['sites'].diff()
df['diff'].fillna(df.sites, inplace=True)
countries = df.countries.unique()
code = df.ctry_code.unique()
pct_change = df.pct_change

x_coord = df.groupby('countries')['diff'].apply(lambda x: x.values) #convert the columns into numpy 2D array

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,5), facecolor = "#FFFFFF")

# use a colormap
cmap = plt.cm.RdBu

bars = []

for i, (color, x_c, country) in enumerate(zip(colors,x_coord, countries)):
    bar = ax.broken_barh([x_c], (i-0.2,0.4),facecolors=cmap(0.7),alpha= 0.2)
    bars.append(bar)
    
gradientbars(bars, ax)
    
ax.scatter( df.sites, df.countries, marker="D", s=3000, color = colors)

ax.set(xlim=[0, 16], ylim=[-1, 3])

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,20,5),labels = [0,5,10,15])
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="major",length=0,labelsize=14,colors= '#C8C9C9')

# Major ticks every 20, minor ticks every 5
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 16, 1)
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-', alpha=0.4, color = "#C8C9C9")
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.yticks([])
plt.box(False)


labels = ['2004','2022']
colors = ["#5375D4","#CC5A43",]
lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color=c,  marker='D',linestyle='', markersize=25,) for c in colors]
leg = ax.get_legend()
plt.figlegend( lines,labels,
           labelcolor="#C8C9C9",
           bbox_to_anchor=(0.3, 0.00), loc="lower center",
            ncols = 2,frameon=False, fontsize= 25)
```

Which gives you the result:

[image]

Comment: I tried the gradient function but couldnt make it work. Always have troubles with cmaps...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The example below using `add_horizontal_gradient()` closely approximates a continuous gradient. It's a relatively simple approach, using `plt.scatter()` to fill in the width of the bar using coloured markers. Also included is labelling and annotation for each bar.

You could alternatively draw a coloured line using `LineCollection` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78008812/21896093), [docs example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html)) but that requires more code for a similar effect.

[image]

Usage (including optional label & annotation):

```py
...

for i, (color, x_c, country) in enumerate(zip(colors,x_coord, countries)):
    add_horizontal_gradient(
        ax=ax, x_start=x_c[0], x_width=x_c[1], y=i,
        label=country, annotation=f"{x_c[1]/x_c[0] * 100:+.0f}%"
    )

...
```

The function:

```py
def add_horizontal_gradient(
    ax, x_start, x_width, y,
    start_color='tab:red', end_color='tab:blue', thickness=700, alpha=0.01,
    label=None, annotation=None, label_shift=0.5
):
    from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='', colors=[start_color, end_color])
    
    lines_per_width = 400 / 2 #tune to get higher marker density
    xs = np.linspace(x_start, x_start + x_width, num=round(lines_per_width * x_width))
    
    ax.scatter(xs, [y] * len(xs), c=xs, cmap=cmap, alpha=alpha, marker='|', s=thickness)
    
    if label:
        ax.annotate(
            text=label, xy=(x_start, y),
            color='gray', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold',
            horizontalalignment='right',
            verticalalignment='center',
            rotation=45,
        )
    
    if annotation:
        ax.annotate(
            text=annotation,
            xy=(xs.mean(), y),
            color='darkslategray', fontsize=8, fontweight='bold',
            horizontalalignment='center',
            verticalalignment='center'
        )
```

Comment: You could include the sign into the number string, making it work both for positive and negative values: `f"{x_c[1]/x_c[0]*100:+.0f} %"`.  For the annotation, you could use `va='right', ha='center'` for right alignment and `va='center', ha='center'` to center the text vertically. Otherwise, working with explicit coordinates breaks with new values.

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks for sharing. I've updated the code with your suggestions.

Comment: Clever approach using the marker and thanks for the annotations :)

Comment: My pleasure. Thanks for the comment. I find `plt.scatter` quite versatile, especially since you can easily map variables to its sizes, alphas, and colours etc.